# HTTPS Ajax Request from a Chrome Extension not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that pulls down the RSS feed of Hacker News, which uses HTTPS. Ever since I upgraded to the newest version of the chrome extension manifest, I can't get it to work. The ajax request fails without any explanation.

I'm 99% sure that my javascript code that makes the request is correct, so I think it's a permissions issue.

Here is the permissions and content security policy section from my manifest:

```
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "https://news.ycombinator.com/",
    "http://news.ycombinator.com/",
    "notifications"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://news.ycombinator.com; object-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://news.ycombinator.com"
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

---

Edit:

Here's a link to the Github Repo: https://github.com/adamalbrecht/hacker-news-for-chrome/

Comment: any luck? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do `"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "https://news.ycombinator.com/*",
    "http://news.ycombinator.com/*",
    "notifications"
  ],` because Chrome wants a pattern of permitted hosts. See [this](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html).

Comment: Yeah, I had tried this. No luck. I also tried specifically including the rss url.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me on Chrome 27.0.1438.8, but you didn't post your code so it's not easy to compare results. Here's what I did:

1. Start with the Chrome kittens sample extension.
2. Change manifest permissions to...

   "permissions": [
     "https://news.ycombinator.com/rss"
   ]
3. In popup.js, change searchOnFlickr_ to that same URL.
4. Change showPhotos_ to log e.target.

Then I loaded the extension, right-clicked the browser-action popup, and inspected the element. In the log I saw the expected RSS content in responseText.

Comment: Here's a link to the Github repo, but I'll try checking out that sample extension to see if there are any obvious issues. Thanks!

https://github.com/adamalbrecht/hacker-news-for-chrome/